# Pasar datos de un componente a otro angular 4

Tags: angular4

estoy utilizando angular 4 y el problema es el siguiente,
nose como pasar una variable desde un componente a otro, en el componente 1 obtengo un dato y me gustaria poder guardarlo en una especie de variable global, para poder utilizarla en los demas componentes
pd: no puedo utilizar LocalStorage o SesionStorage por que son datos muy sensibles del cliente.

Comment: Hola Felipe, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Has investigado e intentado algo? Sobre ese intento, nos debes mostrar el codigo y errores o problemas que tienes. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: Porque no usas SesionStorage y guardas el dato con algún encriptado? O usa servicios. Igualmente como dijo @lois6b desdes poner código y mostrar claramente que quieres lograr.

Comment: Si un intruso tiene acceso al navegador, da igual si está en sessionStorage o en una variable de JS: la seguridad depende de que el usuario tenga su PC/tablet accesible o no

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres enviar (variable) es de componente padre a hijo tienes que utilizar el decorador `@Input()`, si es al revés tienes que utilizar `@Output` y `EventEmitter`, si es entre componentes 'hermanos' la mejor opción es por medio de un `service` y `rxjs`. Comparte algo de código para ver qué tienes hasta ahora

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear este componente para las variables globales :- “app.global.ts”

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppGlobals {
    readonly baseAppUrl: string = 'http://localhost:57431/';
    readonly baseAPIUrl: string = 'https://api.github.com/';
}
```

luego lo usas en tu proyecto llamandolo asi :

```
import { AppGlobals } from '../shared/app.globals';

lo llamas en el constructor:
    constructor(private userService: UserService, private _global: AppGlobals) { }

//GET USERS SERVICE ON PAGE LOAD.

 this.userService.getAPIUsers(this._global.baseAPIUrl + users/hadley/orgs').subscribe(data => this.users = data);
```

===================================================
para variables globales .